# How does Index update works when index key is updated in table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, indexing, database-schema

I used to think before that when I update a indexed column in table, at the same time index is also updated. But during one of my interview, interviewer was stressing that it doesn't work that way. For any update in base table, index will rebuild/reorganize. Although I am pretty sure that this can't happen as both operations are very costly, still want to make sure with expert's view.

While thinking about this, one more thing came to my mind. Say I have index column values 1-1000. So as per B-Tree structure, say value 999, will go to right most nodes from top to bottom. Now if I updated this column from 999 to 2, a lot of shuffling will be required to adjust this value in the index B-Tree. How it will be taken care if index rebuild/reorganize doesn't happen after base table update.

Comment: The B-tree isn't full or  balanced, it just moves it to correct place, and if it doesn't fit, the index page will be split into 2.

Comment: But in my example where I say update 999 to 2, a lot of shifting might require depending on levels of nodes in tree. So will it do those shifting only or will it do rebuild or reorganize?

Comment: It will only move that one record, the other records will remain -- and that's why you need to do rebuild / reorg because indexes will get fragmentation

Comment: That's great James... even I was thinking same way. But as I mentioned about interview part, so wanted to reconfirm. BTW.. do you have anyway to prove this? I tried to search a lot but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any links to material. Most likely stuff like this can be found for example from session recordings from old PASS Summits (sqlpass.org), there's a lot of sessions with technical details about indexing internals.

Comment: No issue James... at least I am more confident now about my concepts :). Thanks for all your help and time James.

Answer (score 0):

> I used to think before that when I update a indexed column in table,
>   at the same time index is also updated.

Yes, that's true. As is for deletes and inserts.

Other indexing systems, may work differently and need to be updated incrementally or rebuild in its entirely separate from the indexed data. This may be confusing.

Statistics need to be updated separately. (See other active discussions in this group.)

> For any update in base table, index will rebuild/reorganize.

No, but if SQL Server cannot fit the node in it's physical place a page split may occur. Or when a key value changes a single psychical row movement may occur.

Both may causes fragmentation. Too much fragmentation may cause performance issues. That's why DBA's find it necessary to reduce fragmentation by rebuilding or reorganizing an index at a convenient time.

> Say I have index column values 1-1000. So as per B-Tree structure, say value 999, will go to right most nodes from top to bottom. Now if I updated this column from 999 to 2, a lot of shuffling will be required to adjust this value in the index B-Tree. How it will be taken care if index rebuild/reorganize doesn't happen after base table update.

Only the changed row is moved to another slot in another page in the B-Tree. The original slot will remain empty. If the new page is full, a page split occurs. This causes a change in the parent page, which may another page split occur if that page is also full, and so on. Al those events may cause fragmentation which may cause performance degradation.

Comment: Could you share the source where you learned about these points?